# weird behavior of nmake under gsh.exe on windows10

Tags: shell, cmd, prompt, nmake

Please help me troubleshoot the following problem I am facing with my app.

I have written my own shell for windows, named gsh, which currently implements most of the CMD.EXE functionality. So far all activities I perform under GSH are identical to CMD, except for this issue I have with the NMAKE program.

Here's  the test scenario. I have several c++ projects built using 'nmake all' on command prompt. Under CMD, nmake runs smoothly (meaning it builds all the targets that need to be built). Under GSH, however, namke builds the first set of targets ( i.e. all *.obj for *.cpp) but not the *.exe that depend on the newly bult *.obj. I have to run 'nmake all' a second time to built the *.exe.
If I run 'nmake clean' before 'nmake all' then all targets are built fine.

I am 100% sure makefile is correct. I have checked all environment variables between GSH and CMD and they are the same. I have also checked the dates on the produced files and they look fine(meaning dates on produced files are newer, and date of *.exe is older than the date of the depending *.obj). I can also confirm that while 'nmake all' is running, it does not invoke another copy of the shell (to do its tasks, which might caused a problem to nmake). Note: On a complex makefile, I can see nmake issuing system(...) function which invokes the shell pointed by ComSpec env var, which I can direct it to either GSH or CMD, without any apparent change in behavior.

Thank you all for any ideas you might have on the root cause of the above.

cheers!, gt

Comment: It's almost certainly the `system()` calls. Try logging them, and seeing whether the commands behave slightly differently between shells.

Comment: Of course I did. I log all invokes to gsh.exe. On a simple makefile like "all: foo.exe /foo.exe: foo.obj / foo.obj: foo.cpp ) system() is not called. I do not get anything in the log file, yet foo.exe is not built...